# How to change folder permission with chroot

Tags: permissions, chroot

So I played around some with display managers, and when I switched to LightDm it said in terminal to change file permission to root for /home/user/.config being tired I didn't really think about what I was doing but now I can't access my computer anymore. I can boot it up if I insert bootable usb and I can access those files there, but I don't know how I can change file permission for user that does not exist in bootable usb.

I am using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. If anyone is such an idiot as I was. I created a new partition, installed another ubuntu 18.04 on it with same username, then I mounted the other drive on the new installation and I was able to change the user permissions for the config folder. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Two options come into my mind:

1. Either boot from an USB stick (or something similar), mount `/` (or `/home`) as
   read-write and then issue `chown` with the ***numerical userid*** instead
   of the textual one:

   ```
   chown -R noon:noon /home/noon/.config
   chown: invalid user: ‘noon:noon’

   chown -R 1000:1000 /home/noon/.config
   # -> works, even if 1000:1000 doesn't exist on the USB stick version
   ```

   Of course, the `1000` should match the actual id of user `noon` on the 
   installed system. Check that in the installed system's `/etc/passwd` file.
2. Or boot into recovery mode from the grub menu, drop to a root shell and from 
   there run

   ```
   chown -R noon:noon /home/noon/.config
   ```